# How to include mvcSiteMapNode for actions having parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, mvcsitemapprovider

I am stuck on one point, I have applied recently breadcrumb using MVC3 sitemap. It is working fine for actions where no parameter is there or all parameters have default values. Only problem is when I try it with action having some parameter(with no default values) like in action

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
```

How to include mvcSiteMapNode for such kind of action. I tried using

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="EditTraining"
                  controller="HotelPolicy"
                  action="Create"
                  preservedRouteParameters="id"/>
```

but still of no use. Please someone suggest how to implement it.

Comment: well for starters, your action is `Edit` and in the sitemapnode you've got `Create`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MvcSitemapProvider - Add value to ignore in url resolver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21561022/mvcsitemapprovider-add-value-to-ignore-in-url-resolver)

Comment: @markpsmith NightOwl888 thanks guys, as stated by marksmith I was creating for Edit and action written was 'Create'